# Invitation sent by TestFlight is the one of the previous build

Tags: ios, testflight

Every time I upload a new build of my app to Testflight, I receive an invitation with the detail of the previous build.
For example, I just posted the build 1.6. At this very moment, all my test group members received an invitation to download and test the build 1.5.
Oddly, when they tap on the link, they are redirected to the Testflight app where they can download the build 1.6 as expected.

Did you experiment the same behaviour ? Did I miss something ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, I too observed this weird behavior of TestFlight